# Can I get notified when a Tag Edit is Rejected please?

Tags: bug, notifications, suggested-edits

I made some edits on the tag  for [e-commerce](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e-commerce), but I wasn't made aware that it was rejected. Given that I have enough reputation to suggest / write tag wikis, I'd have expected to get a notification on this.

Here is my Activity Stream today
[image]

Here is the Activity Stream from Kaiser showing the Rejects
[image]